# Redirecting website users

Tags: php, html

I want to prohibit users from using my website if they are using any form of Internet Explorer? How could I write a php script to redirect the user to a different page if using IE?

Thanks

Comment: You should use JavaScript for this, not PHP.

Comment: -1 no research effort. Did you even consider googling this before asking here? Literally thousands of websites with the answer to this question.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? Do you have any idea of how many people use IE? I mean, I know IE has its problems, but I would not go as far as annoying many web users because of it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick server-side.

```
<?php
    function ae_detect_ie()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
        (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    [...]

    if(ae_detect_ie()) 
        header('Location:/my_IE_webpage.php'); 
?>
```

Source: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/how_to_detect_internet_explorer_with_php.xml

You can also do it client-side using Javascript:

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}

if(getInternetExplorerVersion() > 0) 
    window.location.href = "/my_IE_webpage.php";
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT**

Or use [Vulcan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1247781/vulcan)'s solution (client-side too):

> ```
> <!--[if IE]>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     window.location = "http://example.com";
> </script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Comment: No need of repeating others answers.

Comment: Vulcan: maybe we should've left our comments here after all... --- itachi: I will repeat what I said to Vulcan, which he agreed and we decided to remove our comments here. "I did cite you and added a link to your profile. I thought merging all alternatives into the top post was a good idea for future visitors that would be looking for what OP asked (which was a server-side solution to detecting IE). That way, they can see all alternatives in a single post instead of quickly taking the first solution and leave. This is a wiki after all. ;-)"

Comment: :In that case, put it as community wiki. The option is already there.

Comment: Done. Are you happy now? I will quote the FAQs for you: "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Answer (score 0):

You might find JavaScript easier for this than PHP.  With JavaScript, you could surround a script in an IE conditional statement so that it only runs if the user is running IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://example.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```